# How to resume from rescue clause in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, exception, rescue

How can I write resuming into loops in Ruby? Here is a sample code.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
#

a = [1,2,3,4,5]

begin
    a.each{|i|
        puts i
    if( i==4 ) then raise StandardError end # Dummy exception case
    }
rescue =>e
  # Do error handling here
  next # Resume into the next item in 'begin' clause
end
```

However, when running, Ruby returns the error message

```
test1.rb:13: Invalid next
test1.rb: compile error (SyntaxError)
```

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `retry` instead of `next`; But this will cause infinite loop (`retry` restart from the beginning of the `begin`)

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
begin
    a.each{|i|
        puts i
        if  i == 4 then raise StandardError end
    }
rescue =>e
    retry # <----
end
```

If you want skip an item, and continue to next item, catch the exception inside the loop.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a.each{|i|
    begin
        puts i
        if  i == 4 then raise StandardError end
    rescue => e
    end
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Move your exception catching into the `each` block e.g:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a.each do |i|
  puts i
  begin
  # Dummy exception case
  if( i==4 ) then raise StandardError end

  rescue =>e
    # Do error handling here
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think you need `next`, bihaid.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yeah, I didn't think through the code, I just modified the OP's code to reflect what he needed to do, `next` really would not make a difference here as you have observed, thanks, and be nice with my handle :)

Comment: ah, yes, make that a j.

Comment: `begin .. rescue` encloses no statement.